# I want a hibernate query for the following SQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to make a hibernate query where

I am getting multiple **employee id's** and **single leaveId**.

I have designed the working MySql query for the following :

```
select * from lms_employee_leave_records 
         where (employee_id=2633 or  
                employee_id=2634 or employee_id=2635) 
                and leave_category_id=1;
```

I have made a sample query :
What query should i make because there may be N no. of employees in the query but the leave id will be only one. So what I've designed is :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.or(c1,c2), c3));
```

But the problem is that in OR , I am not able to set the multiple employee id for :

```
Restrictions.eq("employee.employeeId", employee.getEmployeeId())
```

Comment: you can use the same native query if you want .. hibernate will take care of mapping to your entity class .. have you tried anything ??

Comment: How to use this as native query?

Comment: session.createSQLQuery()

Comment: But the requirement in the project is the use of hard-core Hibernate. So please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create  entity mappings for your table lms_employee_leave_records as EmployeeRecords

More on mapping here
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html

(I assume when you create you entity the member name that you would use are the same as the column name in your table)

With hibernate native API you will have two options

**HQL**

Below is your query in HQL you could use

```
from EmployeeRecords as e
     where e.employee_id in (2633,2634,2635)
            and e.leave_category_id=1;
```

execute the above query by using createQuery() on session

More on HQL here

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

**Criteria**

Below is you query in criteria

```
session.createCriteria(EmployeeRecords.class)
.add(Restrictions.in("employee_id",list)) //list will have list of emp ids
.add(Restrictions.eq("leave_category_id",1))
.list()
```

More on criteria here

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html

**EDIT**

Instead of this

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.or(c1,c2), c3));
```

You could do this

```
    Criterion c1=Restrictions.eq("employee_Id", empId1);
    Criterion c2=Restrictions.eq("employee_Id", empId2);
    Criterion c3=Restrictions.eq("employee_Id", empId1);

    Criterion or=Restrictions.or(c1,c2,c3);

    session.createCriteria(EmployeeRecords.class)
    .add(or)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("leave_category_id",1))
    .list()
```

empId1,empId2 , empId3 will be you variables holding the emp ids

Comment: What query should i make because there may be N no. of employees in the query but the leave id will be only one. So what I've designed is :
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.or(c1,c2), c3));
But the problem is that in OR , I am not able to set the multiple employee id for : 
Restrictions.eq("employee.employeeId", employee.getEmployeeId())

Comment: please also update your question with the criteria query you have tried

Comment: Hi @Zulfi , i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

```
List al = new ArrayList();
                        al  .add(2633);
                        al.add(2634);
                        al.add(2635);
                        Criteria ct = getSession().createCriteria(EmployeeLeaveRecords.class)
                                .add(Restrictions.eq("leave_category_id",1))
                                .add(Restrictions.in("employee_id", al));
```